# randomly allocating factor variables into different groups using r

Tags: r, cut, random

I have a list of 9 factor variables: `item <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i")`. I would like to randomly allocate each of the 9 factor variables to 3 groups.
I tried this script but it might be a lot of work:

```
gp1 <- sample(item,3,replace=F)
> gp1
[1] "b" "h" "g"
```

I also tried the cut function but the variables have to be numeric:

```
gp <- cut(item, breaks = 3)
Error in cut.default(item, breaks = 3) : 'x' must be numeric
```

The expected output should look like this but with variables randomly allocated to each group:

```
grp1  grp1  grp3
d      b     i
c      e     h
a      g     f
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sample the items and put it in a `matrix` (which can also be converted to a `data.frame` if you so desire):

```
matrix(sample(item), ncol = 3)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] "b"  "d"  "a" 
## [2,] "f"  "i"  "e" 
## [3,] "h"  "g"  "c"
```

If the items won't split to equal lengths, you might consider `split`, where the splitting variable is based on the shuffling of how many groups you want.

For instance:

```
item <- item[-c(1, 2)]
split(item, sample(rep(1:3, length.out = length(item))))
## $`1`
## [1] "c" "e" "i"
## 
## $`2`
## [1] "f" "g"
## 
## $`3`
## [1] "d" "h"
##
```

Comment: I like the first matrix(sample(item), ncol = 3) but could not really get the second approach. How would you split the factor variables if they cannot be split into equal numbers (e.g. n=11)?

Comment: @baz, note that for the second approach, I've truncated your "item" vector by removing 2 values (n = 7) so I could not split them into equal numbers. Because of that, I've suggested keeping it as a `list` instead of a rectangular data structure *if this is a characteristic of your actual data*....

Comment: the second approach is clearer now after your explanation above.